# SQL Server : WHERE clause case with between

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a script which I want to extract values from db accordingly with some dates.

I have a function which return a date, this date can be currentDate - 1 month, or can be curentDate -2 months. The function is

```
set @syssDate = DATEADD(month, -1, @syss_date);
```

and I have declared a start date:

```
declare @start_quarter datetime
set @start_quarter = '2015-07-01';
```

All I want in my `WHERE` clause to add a

```
case
   when syssDate = start_quarter 
      then bu.date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-10-01'
       else   -- another date
```

My query looks like:

```
    declare @start_quarter datetime
    set @start_quarter = '2015-01-01';

    declare @actual_Date datetime
    set @actual_Date = DATEADD(month, -1, @rollover_date);


        select sum(t.Revenue) as  Revenue  from (
             select sum(bu.value) as Revenue
                  from bus_category_for bu
                      join bus_category buc on buc.id=bu.bus_category_id
                      join bus bu on  bu.id=buc.bus_id
                   where buc.type_id=18 and bu.id=21 and 
--Here I want to add a case statement
bu.date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-10-01'
```

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) which can return **one., atomic value** - it is **NOT** a flow control statement, so you cannot have entire blocks of code inside it.

Comment: And how to solve it? How can I use `case` statement???

Comment: This is not a good situation for a `CASE` - you'd have to have **two** `CASE` expressions - one for the first date and another one of the second date in your `BETWEEN` ..... better use one of the solutions provided by those who already answered

Comment: People learning SQL frequently jump to trying to use `CASE` when they'd in fact be better served by simply application of boolean operators - `AND` and `OR` and some parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Guess you need something like this

```
SELECT Sum(t.Revenue) AS Revenue
FROM   (SELECT Sum(bu.value) AS Revenue
        FROM   bus_category_for bu
               JOIN bus_category buc
                 ON buc.id = bu.bus_category_id
               JOIN bus bu
                 ON bu.id = buc.bus_id
        WHERE  buc.type_id = 18
               AND bu.id = 21
               AND ( ( @syssDate = @start_quarter
                       AND bu.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-10-01' )
                      OR ( another date ) ))a
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
WHERE   (syssDate = start_quarter AND bu.date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-10-01')
    OR   (yssDate <> start_quarter AND bu.date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-10-01')
```

Generally, it's advisable not to use `between` for dates. It's better to use `bu.date >= '2015-01-01' AND bu.date < '2015-10-02'`. See [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: The advice is actually to use `<` for the second comparison, rather than `<=`. Using `>=` and `<=` is exactly equivalent to `BETWEEN`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the correction, was typing to fast... Edited to correct.

Comment: I will say `between` works as it should. Its ours misunderstanding and wrong perception

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I appreciate your help, I will vote up your answer, I marked the VR46's answer correct, because he was first. Thank you one more time, and thank you all for advises.